# iPad iOS3.2 and advertising

Tags: ipad, ads, ios32

Are there (good) ways to deliver paid-for ads to iPads running iOS3.2?

iAd works on iOS4.0 and higher, and AdMob seems to support only the iPhone/iPod Touch devices, not the iPad.

Answer (score 1):

AdMob supports the iPad, and they provide a couple of different banner sizes specifically for it: 320x270, 488x80, and 748x110, all defined in `AdMobView.h`. If you don't have those options available, you probably need to download an updated version of the AdMob SDK.

Comment: I'll check this and see if it's right for me. I'm a bit pressed for time so I might condition out advertising on iPads with iOS3.2.

Comment: This is not obvious on the AdMob site. As far as I can tell it's not indicated anywhere on their site, even if it is in AdMobView.h. The AdMob site does nothing to suggest I need to look in AdMobView.h. Grr.

Answer (score 0):

Every iPad running iO S3.2 is eligible for a free upgrade to iOS 4; the situation is different from iPhone and iPod touch, where various versions co-exist.

So, I don't think you have to care for iOS 3.2 users on iPad. I think people who buy apps on iPad would surely have updated to iOS 4 by now.

Comment: That's not quite true, there are too many assumptions here. I know some iPad owners who upgraded to iOS4 and some who don't want to, admittedly more did than didn't, but there's no need to limit sales by not caring.

Comment: What was the motivation behind those who didn't want to upgrade? I'm curious.